# How to understand the usage of 'at' in "... followed at a walk"

Tags: prepositions

> ... blood splattered the grass and Hagrid ran with him, up the slope towards the castle.
>
> Very shaken, the Care of Magical Creatures class followed **at a walk**.

I don't understand the usage of the prep '**at**' in the phrase "*at a walk*". I have seen "by walk", but not "at a walk". How should we understand it?

-- From Harry Potter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of *at* is describing how what comes before it is modified by what comes after it.

> The class **followed** *at a walk*.

This means that the class followed behind while walking (rather than running, for instance).

Exactly similar constructions are:

> The horse **chased** *at a gallop*.
>   The invalid **moved** *at a crawl*.

---

Along the same lines, you could also say:

> The car **took the corner** *at high speed*.

The car turned while travelling quickly.

> After I yelled at him, he **handed me the book** *at once*.

He immediately handed me the book after I yelled at him.

Comment: I don't feel "at high speed" or "at once" is quite the same as "at a walk".

Comment: @dan I added a couple of exactly similar sentences.